# $ContextAliases and symbol color

Tags: syntax-highlighting

The example below shows that the symbol `` test`MyFunction `` is still in blue, which suggests that it is not defined. The color is defined in menu  *Edit > Preferences> Appearance > SyntaxColoring > Global symbols that have no value assigned*.

```
context`MyFunction[x : _] := x^2
$ContextAliases["test`"] = "context`"
test`MyFunction[5]
```

[image: Symbol Coloring]

How can the front-end be informed about `$ContextAliases` so that `` test`MyFunction `` is black instead of blue?

Note that `` AppendTo[$ContextPath,"context`"] `` does not help.

Answer (score 2):

As a trying of possible solutions, there is an ad-hoc method from the definition of `DeclareKnownSymbols`,

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd@FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
    "test`",
    {},
    {{"test`",{},{},"MyFunction",{}}},
    Directory[],
    <||>
]
```

then

[image]

To automate the coloring you can further build a function by

1. get all the symbols of `` context`* `` by `` Names["context`*"] ``;
2. color them by `UpdateKernelSymbolContexts`;
3. dynamically evaluate this function by monitoring `` Names["context`*"] ``.